# Problems with PHP form validation

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, slider

My form is spread across two pages. Pages are turned using the JS slider called Slick. After filling in the form and clicking the send button on page 2, the validation says I didn't fill in my name. You can see this for yourself on this website: [Rofordaward](http://www.rofordaward.co.uk/nominate.html). Just complete the nomination form and push send. HTML and PHP code below.

HTML

```html
SNIPPET OF FORM (from nominate.html):

<form action="nominate.php" method="post">

  <div class="single-item slider">
    <div class="page1">
      <label class="row">
        <h2 class="headline">Your full name</h2>
        <input type="text" name="yourname" placeholder="Forename and surname"></input>
      </label>

      <label class="row email">
        <h2 class="headline">Your email address <p>Don't worry, we won't spam you or share your email address</p></h2>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="example@rofordaward.co.uk"></input>

      </label>

      <label class="row">
        <h2 class="headline">Name of company</h2>
        <input type="text" name="companyname" placeholder="e.g. Roford"></input>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="page2">
      <label class="row reason">
        <h2 class="headline">Reason for nomination</h2>
        <textarea id="textarea" rows="6" cols="25" maxlength="1000" name="reason" placeholder="A brief evidence based summary"></textarea>
        <div id="text-area-wrap">
          <div id="textarea_feedback"></div>
        </div>
      </label>

      <div class="row button-wrap">
        <div class="column small-12">
          <input class="button" type="submit" value="Send it!">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>
```

PHP

```
    /* Check all form inputs using check_input function */
    $yourname = check_input($_POST['yourname'], "Enter your name");
    $email    = check_input($_POST['email']);
    $companyname    = check_input($_POST['companyname']);
    $reason = check_input($_POST['reason'], "Write your reason");

    /* If e-mail is not valid show error message */
    if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/", $email))
    {
        show_error("E-mail address not valid");
    }

    /*Message for the e-mail */
    $message = "New submission

    Name: $yourname
    E-mail: $email
    Company name: $companyname

    Reason:
    $reason

    End of message
    ";

    /* Send the message using mail() function */
    mail($myemail, $subject, $message);

    /* Redirect visitor to the thank you page */
    header('Location: thanks.htm');
    exit();

    /* Functions used */
    function check_input($data, $problem='')
    {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        if ($problem && strlen($data) == 0)
        {
            show_error($problem);
        }
        return $data;
    }

    function show_error($myError)
    {
    ?>
        <html>
        <body>

        <b>Please correct the following error:</b><br />
        <?php echo $myError; ?>

        </body>
        </html>
    <?php
    exit();
    }
    ?>
```

When I remove the scripts for the JS slider, the form becomes fully functional.

Comment: It was pointed out that the name used in the email input box (name="youremail") didn't match that of the PHP ($email    = check_input($_POST['email']);).

I have amended this. The issue with the name failing validation still stands though.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website and I didn't realise what I had done. I will remove the code snippet for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP Code, You are using `$_POST['email']` which suits good according to code on your last HTML Block when `<input type="text" name="email" />` as you have set it to `'email'`

On other hand, in your First HTML Code Block:

```
<label class="row email">
        ....
        <input type="text" name="youremail" ....></input>
 </label>
```

You set `name="youremail"`, which is definitely going to derive wrong result with your PHP Code. You should be using it like `$_POST['youremail']` in your PHP Code to get it working.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't see that. Fixing that has solved part of the problem, but the name still fails to validate.

Comment: I don't know, but you can go to http://www.rofordaward.co.uk/nominate.html and see for yourself. It uses the same code as above for the form.

Comment: I've tried that and it didn't fix it. I removed the JS for the slider and afterwards the form started working correctly. However, this isn't an ideal solution since I need the slider. Any ideas why the JS slider would be doing this?

Comment: Since it's an another issue, you may raise a new question for that particular issue. Is your JavaScript setting some values to form, you may consider reviewing it.

Comment: Okay, I shall review my JavsScript and see if I can find the problem. If not, I shall raise a new question. Thank you for your time and apologies for making newby mistakes.